# Homotopy groups of a covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

This is a question related to the exercise 2218 from the book "Problems and Solutions in Mathematics" by Ta-Tsien, $2^{nd}$ Ed.

*Let $Z$ denote the figure 8 space, $Z = X \vee Y$, $X$ and $Y$ circles. Les $x,y \in \pi_1(Z,*)$ be the elements in $Z$ defined by $X$, $Y$, where $*$ denotes the vertex.*

Part of the first question is:

*Let $h:\pi_1(Z,*) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ be the homomorphism satisfying $h(x)=2$ and $h(y)=3$, and let $p:\tilde{Z}\rightarrow Z$ denote the covering space corresponding to the kernel of h. ($p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{Z},*)))=ker(h).$)*

And, in the solution, the following statement is made:

*Since $h(x)=2$ and $h(y)=3$ and $\pi_1(Z,*)$ is generated by $x$ and $y$, it follows that the homomorphism $h$ is surjective. Thus $\pi_1(Z,*)/ ker(h)$ is isomorphic to the group $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}_6$.*

Followed by the statement I do not understand:

*Hence the covering space $p:\tilde{Z}\rightarrow Z$ is a 6-fold cover.*

How do you deduce this last statement from the previous one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every regular covering map $p$ with the covering group $G$, by the definition of $G$ we have that $p$ is n-to-one map where $n$ is the order of $G$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still do not see what role the quotient group is playing. I understand from the first isomorphism theorem, that $\pi_1(Z,*)/ ker(h)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. But why is a quotient group used to determine the number of folds of the cover ?

Comment: Quotient group is the group of covering transforms.

Comment: Searching for the notions you mentioned, I found out there is a whole chapter in "Algebraic Topology" by Hatcher with very visual examples. I guess the most relevant relative to this discussion would be the chapter on deck transformations.

Comment: I get it now, thank you.